# Freezes, Crashing Programs, Graphics Glitches, and occasional BSOD after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, bsod, windows-8.1-upgrade

Back when Windows 8.1 was first released, I upgraded to it almost immediately. Upon finishing the upgrade, I was greeted with display artifacts, crashes, crashing programs, and BSODs. I tried driver updates, software updates, and even tried disabling all startup programs. Nothing worked. It even did this in safe mode. I even tried a complete reinstall of 8.1 from scratch in case it was an upgrade-related issue. Same problems. So that same weekend, I did a complete fresh install of Windows 8 to rollback.

Fast forward to 2 weeks ago: Microsoft crammed windows 8.1 down my throat after replacing the "You can upgrade to Windows 8.1 for free" message with "We've downloaded Windows 8.1 and it will be installed next time you restart". I tried to avoid that as long as possible by postponing the restart, but eventually the postpone option didn't have the "not right now" option, but merely a delay of up to "8 hours" before they would screw up my entire system for me.

So here I am hopeful that they or my hardware vendors have resolved the issues that led to the insane instability of my system last time. Sadly, that's not the case. Since the upgrade a couple weeks back, I've been plagued by the same line of issues. Random freezes while using the computer, freezing while shutting down, graphics glitches in all applications that use 3D libraries, and the occasional BSOD. When the computer freezes, there's nothing in the event logs.

All my windows updates are installed, all my drivers are up to date. I've even tried removing all my drivers and rebooting to let Windows install the ones it wants to. Nothing seems to fix this. My external hard drive is now completely borked and I've lost all the data on it from the random crashes and freezes. Some mornings I come in and find my fans all in overdrive only to turn the monitor on and see that the system is frozen and has been since some low AM digits since that's the time locked on the clock. It's driving me up a wall and I don't even know where to go from here. My system specs (as exported from Speccy) are below in case that helps anyone. I'd appreciate any kind of suggestions/thoughts of any kind as I'm willing to try anything at this point. It's interfering with my work and my play.

```
Summary
        Operating System
            Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
        CPU
            AMD FX-8350 23 °C
            Vishera 32nm Technology
        RAM
            32.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 668MHz (11-11-11-28)
        Motherboard
            ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. M5A99FX PRO R2.0 (Socket 942) 31 °C
        Graphics
            H233H (1920x1080@60Hz)
            HP w2408 (1920x1200@60Hz)
            2048MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series (Sapphire/PCPartner)   38 °C
        Storage
            232GB Samsung SSD 840 Series (SSD)  30 °C
            931GB Seagate ST1000DL002-9TT153 (SATA) 31 °C
            465GB Seagate ST500DM002-1BD142 (SATA)  31 °C
            232GB Western Digital WDC WD25 00JB-22REA0 USB Device (SSD) 30 °C
            465GB Seagate ST350082 0AS USB Device (SSD) 30 °C
        Optical Drives
            ASUS DRW-24B1ST c
        Audio
            Realtek High Definition Audio
Operating System
    Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
    Computer type: Desktop
    Installation Date: 10/13/2014 2:13:19 PM
```

Also unfortunately I don't have any of the BSOD codes at this time. I haven't seen one in a couple weeks now (since the driver updates), so I'm hoping at least that portion of this is resolved. If I get another one, I'll update this with the codes/details of the BSOD.

Comment: Have you tried a memory test?

Comment: We need BSOD information if you want help with BSODs.

Comment: Well the BSODs are one of many symptoms of the upgrade, and may have been fixed with the driver updates I did since I haven't seen one since. I just listed the symptom since it was present at one point. @EricF I'll run a memory test after work today and see if that turns up anything, but I've had zero, zip, zilch issues with this system for years. So it's pretty unlikely I've coincidentally developed memory issues and hardware failure that just happened to coincide with the 8.1 upgrade.